# Laravel Auth User after registration and redirect to specific URL

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

Users can register only when they choose "package", then popup will show and they must click create your account. After registration I want to redirect them back + use Auth()->login($user) function without redirecting them to the their panel.

```
protected function register(Request $request)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'surname'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
    try {
        $validatedData['password']        = bcrypt(array_get($validatedData, 'password'));
        $validatedData['activation_code'] = str_random(30).time();
        $validatedData['username']        = $request->name.$request->surname.str_random(8);
        $validatedData['slug']            = str_slug($request->name . " " . $request->surname, '-');
        $user                             = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'klijent')->first());
        $notif = new Notifikacije;
        $notif->user_id = $user->id;
        $notif->save();
        // $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        logger()->error($exception);

        return $exception;
    }
    // $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Uspešno ste se registrovali!');
```

This Auth()->login($user) is actually a problem, when i use that it will redirect them to the "redirectedTo" variable in Login Controller, and then its skipping the line with message "Uspesno ste se registrovali").

Also, when I delete this "Auth()->login it redirect me to the registration page, not previous page with list of packages but message shows up: "Uspešno ste se registrovali"

Comment: After registration, do you want users to automatically logged in to your panel ? Or do you want users to logged after email verification ?

Comment: Are you sure `auth()->login($user)` is the problem here? Usually (if not overwritten) this method will save the authenticated state and not redirect or even modify the response in any way.

Comment: There is no email verification, i fixed it with intended session, i couldn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess here, but could it be that `redirect()->back()` returns you back to the registration page but because it's protected and [only accessible for guests](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/stubs/Auth/RegisterController.stub#L41) (e.g. protected by the `guest` middleware) the guest middleware [will redirect](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L22) to the path defined in the [RouteServiceProvider::HOME constant](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L24)?

Comment: You mean, after registration and users automatically logged in, redirection doesn't work because they are not guests anymore?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.